# Juxtaposition of Java instance methods in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

Is it possible to use `juxt` in conjunction with methods of a Java object in Clojure?

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is

```
((juxt .method1 .method2) myinstance)
```

with `.method1` and `method2` being instance methods of `myinstance`, which is an instance of some Java class.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or just make a macro for that, which would combine normal `juxt` behaviour with `.method` behaviour. Something like this:

```
user> (defmacro juxt+ [& fns]
        (let [x (gensym)]
          `(fn [~x] ~(mapv #(list % x) fns))))
#'user/juxt+
```

for example:

```
(juxt+ .getName (partial str "string val: ") .getAbsolutePath vector)
```

expands to the following:

```
(fn*
  ([G__19829]
    [(. G__19829 getName)
     ((partial str "string val: ") G__19829)
     (. G__19829 getAbsolutePath)
     (vector G__19829)]))
```

in repl:

```
user> ((juxt+ .getName 
              (partial str "string val: ") 
              .getAbsolutePath 
              vector) 
         (java.io.File. "aaa"))

["aaa" 
 "string val: aaa" 
 "/Users/.../aaa" 
 [#object[java.io.File 0x34c3af49 "aaa"]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try encapsulating the method calls in anonymous functions:

```
((juxt #(.method1 %) #(.method2 %)) myinstance)
```